# Android - not able to cancel AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I'm  generating 30000 values for every 30 seconds and i'm plotting the graph with that values using `AsyncTask`. The issue is if the second set of values comes i need to cancel running `AsyncTask` and i need to plot the second set of values with `AsyncTask`. But i'm not able to cancel the `AsyncTask`.

Below are the code snippet

```
CountDownTimer ct;
DrawGraphAsync dga;

// onCreate
ct=new CountDownTimer(30*1000, 1000) {
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

    }

    public void onFinish() {
        dga= new DrawGraphAsync();

        if(dga.getStatus()==AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING){
            Log.d("TAG",MainActivity.this.dga.getStatus().toString());
            dga.cancel(true);
        }           
        dga.execute();
        ct.start(); 
    }
}.start();

// InAsyncTask   

@Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        Log.d("TAG","DOINBACK GROUND TASK:: ");
    try{                
            for(int cout=0;cout<30000;cout++){

                if(isCancelled()){
                    Log.d("TAG","CANCELLED DOINBACK:: ");
                    break;
                }
                // Code to paint the graph
            }                          
                }catch(Exception e){                        
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

    return null
}
```

can anyone please help me to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance

Comment: where's your onPostExecute()?

Comment: try to print out `dga.getStatus()` and check whether its value is ever equal to `AsyncTaks.Status.RUNNING`

Comment: It should work, can you specify exactly where in `doInBackground()` you are calling `isCancelled()`?  Where do you generate the 30000 values?

Comment: @YohanBlake I've copied doinbackground code alone. in my app i'm using all asynctask callback methods

Comment: @SebastianWalla s we got status as running

Comment: @DanielNugent  calling isCancelled() inside for loop in doInBackground method. can u pls check above doInBackground method i've updated now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the problem.  You are trying to use your second instance to cancel the first instance:

```
    dga= new DrawGraphAsync();

    if(dga.getStatus()==AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING){
        Log.d("TAG",MainActivity.this.dga.getStatus().toString());

        // this will cancel the task you just allocated that has yet to start.
        // And it leaks the previous task that was allocated
        dga.cancel(true); 

    }           
    dga.execute();
```

Change your onFinish code to this:

```
public void onFinish() {

    if (dga != null) && (dga.getStatus()==AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING) {
        dga.cancel(true);
        dga = null;
    }           

    dga= new DrawGraphAsync();
    dga.execute();
    ct.start(); 
}
```